# How to control number of bars in a bar chart based on date selection by user in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a date parameter which has a week split.
When I select Week 4 I need 4 bars(one for each week viz Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4) in a chart with sum of sales data.
When I select Week 3 I need 3 bars(one for each week viz Week1, Week2, Week3) in a chart with sum of sales data
and so on ...so when I select Week 1, i will have just one bar in my chart.

I tried using DATEDIFF with last() but I am not able to control the number of bars in the bar chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what works for me:

1. Create a parameter based on your date field, call it timeframe (or whatever), Data Type: Date, allowable values: all
2. Create a calculated field with the following formular

`If [Date] < [Timeframe] then [Value] ELSE null END`

with [Date] being your date field and [Value] being the original measure you want to display

3. Use the new calculated field instead of the original measure in your graph
4. Right click on the created parameter and choose " Show parameter controls"

Now when you change the date in the parameter controls, the amount of bar charts will adjust that only the weeks up to that date are displayed.
It should look like this:
[image]

[image]

Edit:
If you wanted an "All" option, you could go to the parameters settings, choose "List" as the "allowable Values" and add the values from your date field.
You then just create an additional item manually with the Value of "01/01/2011" or any other date far in the future) and Display as "All".
**However this will only work if you have static data!** If you update your source and new, more recent values were added, they will not appear in the list since you specified explicitely which values to be available.

I also realized the following:
If you do it like I explained, you will be able to choose particular days, that might lead to different graphs for different days of the same week. Ie if I choose tuesday orfriday of the same week, I will have different sized bars although the sales of the whole week stay obviously the same. If that is alright for your use case, go for it. Otherwise you should create another calculated field with `DATETRUNC("week", [date])` and use that for the paramter and calculation. With that you can only choose the week, so no matter which day of a week you choose the bar will always have the same height.

Comment: Thank you @Alexander ...one other question what if I want to have an "All" option in that parameter?
(selecting All to display all the bars) 
what would the calculated field be like?

Comment: @AshishBSathish added a paragraph about an "all" option, plus another possible flaw of my former description.